# Update variable in ngOnOnit a Angular2

Tags: angular

I recently started learning Angular2 concepts, so I have an issue trying to understand how to change a boolean 'loading' value in ngOnOnit after completing the transaction using .then, my component is retrieving data from the service perfectly. If someone can give me a hand it would be great.

Basically what I want to do is change the value loading to 'false' and hide the 'md-progress-circle' after completing the cycle.

This is my html.

```
<span *ngIf="loading">
 <md-progress-circle mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-circle>
</span>
```

This is my component class.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { DemographicsService } from './app.service-http';
    import { Demographics } from './demographics';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-data',
      templateUrl: 'app/app.data.html',
        styleUrls: ['app/app.data.css']
    })
    export class AppData implements OnInit {

      demographics: Demographics[] = [];
      loading: boolean = false;

      constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private demographicsService: DemographicsService) { 
      }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loading = true;
        this.demographicsService.getDemographics()
          .then(demographics => this.demographics = demographics);
      }
    }
```

Add something like this Inside the .then

`this.loader = false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of `.then` is the function that executes once results arrive. Just add another line of code to do what you want:

```
this.demographicsService.getDemographics().then(
    demographics => {
        this.demographics = demographics;
        this.loading = false;
    }
);
```

One thing to look out for: if the promise is rejected or if an exception occurs, the `loading=false` line will never be executed and the app will remain in an infinite loading state.

To address this, you may want to set loading in the `.finally` block instead. This block gets executed no matter what:

```
this.demographicsService.getDemographics().then(
    demographics => this.demographics = demographics;
).catch( 
    error => { /* TODO: handle the error*/ }
).finally( 
    ()=>this.loading=false 
);
```

Comment: thanks so much, still learning ES2015 concepts (arrow function), much appreciated.

Comment: @Dimitri you're welcome. I added a bit to my answer.